# adjust matplotlib subplot axis + labels after applying tight_layout

Tags: matplotlib, data-visualization, subplot

I am creating this subplot using the grid. The code and output is given below. when I am trying to apply  `plt.tight_layout()` function to adjust labels it did not work fine.

```
def annotate_axes(fig):
for i, ax in enumerate(fig.axes):
    ax.text(0.5, 0.5, "ax%d" % (i+1), va="center", ha="center")
    ax.tick_params(labelbottom=False, labelleft=False)
    ax.set_xlabel('Episode', fontsize=8)
    ax.set_ylabel('LPS',fontsize=8)
    ax.set_title("Learning Rate=0.9", fontsize=8)

fig = plt.figure()
ax1 = plt.subplot2grid((12, 8), (0, 0), colspan=4,rowspan=4)
ax2 = plt.subplot2grid((12, 8), (0, 4), colspan=4,rowspan=4)
ax3 = plt.subplot2grid((12, 8), (4, 1),rowspan=2,colspan=2)
ax4 = plt.subplot2grid((12, 8), (4, 5),rowspan=2,colspan=2)
ax5 = plt.subplot2grid((12, 8), (6, 2), colspan=4,rowspan=4)
ax6 = plt.subplot2grid((12, 8), (10, 0), colspan=2,rowspan=2)
annotate_axes(fig)
plt.tight_layout()
plt.savefig("Plot.png")
plt.show()
```

[image: Output of the above code]

[image: warning]

Comment: For example, add `figsize=(16,9)` to disable the warning. It seems to be due to the fact that there is no margin to reduce it.

Comment: You can also try `constrained_layout` for more complicated layouts like this but use `gridspec` instead of `subplot2grid`

Answer (score 0):

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

def annotate_axes(fig):
    for i, ax in enumerate(fig.axes):
        ax.text(0.5, 0.5, "ax%d" % (i+1), va="center", ha="center")
        ax.tick_params(labelbottom=False, labelleft=False)
        ax.set_xlabel('Episode', fontsize=8)
        ax.set_ylabel('LPS',fontsize=8)
        ax.set_title("Learning Rate=0.9", fontsize=8)

fig = plt.figure(constrained_layout=True)
gs = fig.add_gridspec(12, 8)
ax1 = fig.add_subplot(gs[0:4, 0:4])
ax2 = fig.add_subplot(gs[0:4, 4:8])
ax3 = fig.add_subplot(gs[4:6, 1:3])
ax4 = fig.add_subplot(gs[4:6, 5:7])
ax5 = fig.add_subplot(gs[6:10, 2:6])
ax6 = fig.add_subplot(gs[10:12, 0:2])
annotate_axes(fig)
plt.savefig("Plot.png")
plt.show()
```

[image]